# Security violation on Canvas.ToDataUrl with Base64 Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64, cross-site

I am trying to build some kind of branding tool, which adds a branding to a chosen image and lets the user download the image again. This works perfectly fine on many Browsers, but Opera and IE throw a security Error which makes me think that soon other browsers might throw errors too.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rL8afe0/9/

Commenting out the line makes the code work:

```
ctx.drawImage(branding, 0, 0, 30, 30);
```

The reason is probably some false negative on cross site scripting since my app works on client side.

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you draw images on canvas that don't originate from the same domain as your webpage, then the canvas will automatically be "tainted" with a cross-domain security violation. That is the error you are seeing. When a canvas is tainted `toDataURL` will be prohibited by the browser. The solution is to host the images on the same domain as your web pages.

Comment: There are no images hosted anywhere

Comment: If you mean the images are submitted by the user from their own computer, then those images are deemed "cross-domain" and will cause the security violation errors to be triggered. If this is the case and your users have modern browsers, you can use the new `FileReader` to let the users select files from their own computers in a way that won't cause security violations.

Comment: please take a look at the fiddle, i think that i am doing everything as you suggest. you can try opera on linux or ie on windows for the bug.

Comment: Both IE and Opera will still not let you use the `download` attribute. Here's a link to a cross-browser script to let the user download their canvas content as an image: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some browsers are very strict when using SVG with canvas, incl. for example IE.

As your branding logo is SVG it will taint the canvas in these browsers.

Replacing your branding image with a PNG, JPEG etc. will fix this problem.

Comment: waoh, i just isolated a completely different problem (cannot draw 2 images in the same canvas on opera: https://jsfiddle.net/2rL8afe0/14/) and your approach came from a whole another side. saved me there.